# Can XCode automatically refresh/renew the invalidated "provisioning profile"?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter, cross-platform

i am developing an app for both android and ios using Flutter. The app is already launched in Android and ios platforms, which means available in playstore and Apple App Store. However now we need to add Push notifications. we selected firebase FCM technology for this.

So to enable the Push notifications for ios, we logged into the apple developer console and tried enabling "push notifications" service inside identifier.

Now it says doing this will invalidate/expire the provisioning profiles and we have to renew/refresh the provisioning profiles.

As a developer new to iOS platforms, i didnt get this right. the provisioning profiles we have are managed by xcode it self. Our xcode version is 11.2.1. now, i have the following questions with me.

If I enable this push notifications service and this provisioning profiles got invalid,

what will happen to my existing apps in apple store?

Since my provisioning profiles are managed by xcode, what should i do? Will they automatically get renewed / refreshed by XCode?

Iwhat will happen to my already published apps in Apple Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using XCode 11.2 and Xcode did "repair" my provisioning profiles automatically. I uploaded the app to `TestFlight` to make sure and it worked. So Yes, XCode can repair and re issue the provisioning profile for you.

However to do this, your profile need to be `Automatically managed by XCode`

Answer (score 0):

You can't renew it automatically.
But you need to renew it so you will be able to upload more versions for your app
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/68164

Update:
If you want to be fully 100% sure
You can always ask apple directly by using a TSI ticket which is a paid Code Level Support that you can do from your apple developer account.
I use it many times when I need crucial anwsers.
https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/
Let me know if that helped you or if you need help with that...

Comment: Are you sure it cant be auto renewed? I mean, auto renew by XCode?